# How to comment in package-scripts.js to show up in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, jsdoc, npm-scripts

### **Goal**

I want to display comments of my nps commands from `package-scripts.js` in my `package.json` like this:
[image: desired comment in package.json]

### **Tried**

I actually don't know where the content of this overlay ("Run by the 'npm test' command") is coming from (vscode, npm, nps?). I've looked up all of their GitHub repositories without success.

I've tried to add comments the following way with no results:

```js
// package-scripts.js  
module.exports = {
  scripts: {
    /** Build image */
    build: "docker build"
  }
}
```

```
// package.json
{
  scripts: {
    "build": "nps build"
  }
}
```

**Is it possible at all? How is the shown comment made?**

Comment: Take a look at the examples for [parallel scripts](https://github.com/sezna/nps/blob/master/other/EXAMPLES.md#parallel-scripts) in the _package-scripts examples_ documentation for nps. Maybe it's the [nps-utils](https://github.com/kentcdodds/nps-utils) package that's doing it via its [concurrent](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/kentcdodds/nps-utils/function/index.html#static-function-concurrent) method.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with:

- json schemas in your vscode settings or
- switching to jsonc mode in vscode

Both are documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json.

I suggest to extend the package.json schema https://json.schemastore.org/package to fit your needs, but i don't have any experience with displaying comments as tooltips in vscode.